# Strange behaviour of tileable background beneath div

Tags: css, background, behavior

I have a tileable wood pattern as background in an html page. The background looks perfectly seamless when viewed in Photoshop or any other software, but on the html page it looks discontinuous at the points where my main div element begins and ends.

Here's a preview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yMxT.png

This anomaly persists across different browsers. (I have tested in latest versions of Firefox, Chrome and IE.) What could be the reason behind this?

Let me know if you want to look at a specific part of the code.

**Edit:**

Solved the problem. When asked to post the CSS I noticed that I used the selectors body, html to apply the background-image. Removing html from the selector did the bit.

CSS:

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #455d76;
  background-image: url("images/bg.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

Comment: can you post css for div and html, body

Comment: @Amjad, you can post your solution as an answer to your own question and accept it.  That way the question won't be marked as unanswered for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all whenever asking a question, you should post your code here and not give link to a preview image or your website, because it makes us tough to solve your question.

Coming to your question, from the image it looks like you are using `background-image` property for different element like say for example `div` for `header, main, and footer`, so instead declare that property for `body` tag instead, in your CSS

```
body {
   background-image: url('whatever.png');
   background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Comment: Just posted the CSS and fixed the issue. Removing 'html' from the selector solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. I had used 'body, html' as selector while specifying the background property. Removing 'html' from the selector (ie, leaving just body) did the bit.

(Thanks Mr. Alien, you were right about the background-image property being declared for different elements, ie, body and html in this case.)

Thanks to everyone who answered/commented. :)